# Transit visa or Tourist visa for multiple US layovers

Tags: usa, transit-visas, london, peruvian-citizens

I'm Peruvian and I will be traveling to London.

My outward flight has 1 stop at Miami with an 18 hour layover.
My return flight has 2 stops, a 15 hour stop in New York and a 2 hour stop in Miami.

Can i get a US transit visa, or are the layovers too long?

Also, Is it advisable to stay in a hotel near the airport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A US transit visa allows transits of up to *29 days.*  Presumably this is a relic of an earlier era in which long-distance travel by means other than air was still common. In light of that fact, the time waiting is definitely not too long.

However, since a transit visa and a tourist visa both cost $160, and the tourist visa is valid for 10 years by default for Peruvian nationals, you should consider whether there is any possibility that you will want to visit the US between now and 2028, and if there is you should probably apply for a tourist visa.

Comment: Maybe in a future i will visit the US. But for now i will apply for the transit only. Many thanks!

Comment: The burden of proof is lower for a transit visa so they’re easier to get, so you might have made the right call.